# Will bash script pre-parse the syntax?

Tags: bash, solaris

I am running bash script that needs to run different code for SunOs and Linux and I am getting the syntax error from the part of the code that not supposed to be true. I did not expect that since I thought that Bash works as interpreter.

The bash version on SunOS is 2.5 and on Linux is 4.1. The syntax it complains about is only supported from 3.1 version.

I tried to disable the newer code with "else" clause but it looks like it still pre-parses.

Also my script has ":" instead of "#! /bin/sh" as first line.

test.sh:

```
:
echo "`uname`"
if [ `uname` = "SunOS" ]
 then
    echo "do old stuff"
 else
    echo "new stuff"
    arr=($(grep "^X1" ../foo.txt | sed 's/.*=//'))
fi
```

The error is

```
> ./test.sh
SunOS
./test.sh: syntax error at line 8: `arr=' unexpected
```

If I comment error line then it will work fine:

```
:
echo "`uname`"
if [ `uname` = "SunOS" ]
 then
    echo "do old stuff"
 else
    echo "new stuff"
    #arr=($(grep "^X1" ../foo.txt | sed 's/.*=//'))
fi
```

The result is

```
> ./test.sh
SunOS
do old stuff
```

My question is how do I fix this syntax error without commenting? I have to have "if/else" to be able to run this script on different machines.

Comment: What's only supported from 3.1? The array syntax you're using here was fine in at least 2.05. Are you sure you're running with `bash` and not `sh`?

Comment: what happens if you replace `:` with proper hashtag? Good luck.

Comment: How do I know what exactly is used (bash or sh)? this is executed as part of build process.

Comment: @shelter I replaced it with "#! /bin/sh and the same error happens

Comment: @angie use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @PesaThe yes, #!/bin/bash worked, but I am wondering why ":" was there? this is not my code.

Comment: Note that `bash` is **not** `sh`.  Linux conflates the two, Solaris does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That array syntax has been supported in bash since at least version 2; if you're getting errors there, it's because your script is not running under bash at all, but under some other shell. This probably has a lot to do with your script starting with `:` instead of a shebang line, meaning it's up to whatever runs the script to figure out what to run it with, with inconsistent results. I'd strongly recommend using a proper shebang line. If bash doesn't exist in a predictable location, you could use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. If bash might not be in the `PATH`, you could use something like the script prologue [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/865874/bin-sh-vs-bin-bash-for-maximum-portability/865964#865964) -- a `#!/bin/sh` shebang followed by commands to find and switch to bash.

As for the question about pre-parsing: yes, bash and other shells will parse all the way to the `fi` keyword before executing the `if` construct. They need to find the `then`, `else`, and `fi` keywords in order to figure out what they're going to execute and what they're going to skip, and in order to find those they have to parse their way to them.

Answer (score 1):

You could stick the command in a temporary variable, and then execute the variable if your condition is true.   I just ran the following on my system:

```
> if [ true ]; then echo hi; else [blah]=(--4); fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `--4'
```

I get a syntax error as you describe.   If I then do:

```
> if [ true ]; then echo hi; else var="[blah]=(--4)" && eval "${var}"; fi
hi
```

then it echos hi (no error).   Finally if I do:

```
> if [ ]; then echo hi; else var="[blah]=(--4)" && eval "${var}"; fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `--4'
```

Then it attempted to run the code, and generates an error based on trying to run the code.

Comment: This is pretty close, but you need to use `eval` to parse shell syntax in a string.

Comment: oops, yes... my bad

Comment: You should double-quote variable references, especially when doing dangerous things like `eval` -- `eval "${var}"` instead of `eval ${var}`. Without the double-quotes, you can get *really bizarre* results under some circumstances.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it does not seem to help. It will not print syntax error but it will not fill arr correctly

Comment: Sorry, are you saying in the "new stuff" case it does not fill in the array?.   Try replacing `eval` with `echo` and then cut and paste the output on your command prompt to see if that works correctly.